# Object of arrays pass in function

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, proto

i am trying to pass object of arrays

dto :

```
@InputType('RuleCreateBulkRequest')
export class RuleCreateBulkRequestDto {
    @ApiProperty({ type: () => [RuleInputDto] })
    @Type(() => RuleInputDto)
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    @Field(() => [RuleInputDto])
    bulk?: [RuleInputDto];
}
```

here is my sample data i pass: object of arrays

```
{
 "bulk":[
  {
    name: 'After every minute',
    description: 'Will turn on device after every minute',
    embedded: false,
    triggers: [ [Object] ],
    actions: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    name: 'After every minute',
    description: 'Will turn on device after every minute',
    embedded: false,
    triggers: [ [Object] ],
    actions: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
}
```

here is zero index [0] value from above

```
one {
  name: 'After every minute 1',
  description: 'Will turn on device after every minute',
  embedded: ' false',
  triggers: [ { name: 'TimeTrigger', options: [Object] } ],
  actions: [ { name: 'EntitySetStateAction', options: [Object] } ]
}
```

when i pass it as a object of array in function . i got result like this  .

```
RuleDto {
    embedded: false,
    active: true,
    triggers: '[object Object]',
    actions: '[object Object]',
    id: '71d4c663-182a-4d63-93fd-f9cb30a52f7e',
    name: 'After every minute',
    description: 'Will turn on device after every minute',
    condition: null,
    deletedAt: null,
    cursorId: 398,
    createdAt: 2022-06-20T02:22:59.823Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-06-20T02:22:59.823Z,
    version: 1
  },
  RuleDto {
    embedded: false,
    active: true,
    triggers: '[object Object]',
    actions: '[object Object]',
    id: 'cea158a5-ee1b-4881-839a-06a2d0f3daf6',
    name: 'After every minute',
    description: 'Will turn on device after every minute',
    condition: null,
    deletedAt: null,
    cursorId: 399,
    createdAt: 2022-06-20T02:22:59.823Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-06-20T02:22:59.823Z,
    version: 1
  }
```

how i can get proper values of followings  instead object Object

```
triggers: '[object Object]',
actions: '[object Object]',
```

here are function in which above value pass

// function call

```
const response = await this.service
            .ruleCreateMany(input , ctx  )
             .toPromise();
            console.log('res',response);
```

function def:

```
@GrpcMethod('RulesService')
async ruleCreateMany(
    input: RuleCreateBulkRequestDto,
    _ctx: GrpcContext,
): Promise<{ rules: RuleMessage[] }> {

    

      
    const response = await this.service.createMany({bulk:input.bulk});
    
    
    console.log('from rule controller :', input.bulk[0]);
    console.log('from rule controller bluk  :', input.bulk);
    console.log('from rule controller bluk  :', JSON.stringify (input.bulk));

    

    const rules: RuleDto[] = plainToClass(RuleDto, get(response, 'rules', []));

    console.log('ruler controler ',rules);
    
    const mapperPromises = rules.map((r: RuleDto) => RuleProto.toProto(r));

    return { rules: await Promise.all(mapperPromises) };
}
```

RuleMessage Interface

```
export interface RuleMessage
extends Omit<RuleDto, 'condition' | 'triggers' | 'actions' | 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt' | 'deletedAt'> {
    condition?: string;
    triggers: string;
    actions: string;
    createdAt?: string;
    updatedAt?: string;
    deletedAt?: string;
}

export const RuleProto = {
    toProto(input: RuleDto): RuleMessage {
        return {
            ...input,
            condition: input.condition ? JSON.stringify(input.condition) : undefined,
            triggers: JSON.stringify(input.triggers),
            actions: JSON.stringify(input.actions),
            createdAt: input.createdAt ? input.createdAt.toISOString() : undefined,
            updatedAt: input.updatedAt ? input.updatedAt.toISOString() : undefined,
            deletedAt: input.deletedAt ? input.deletedAt.toISOString() : undefined,
        };
    },
// triggers: JSON.stringify(input.triggers),
//actions: JSON.stringify(input.actions),
    fromProto(input: RuleMessage): RuleDto {
        return {
            ...input,
            condition: input.condition ? JSON.parse(input.condition) : undefined,
            triggers: JSON.parse (JSON.stringify(input.triggers)),
            actions: JSON.parse(input.actions),
            createdAt: input.createdAt ? new Date(input.createdAt) : undefined,
            updatedAt: input.updatedAt ? new Date(input.updatedAt) : undefined,
            deletedAt: input.deletedAt ? new Date(input.deletedAt) : undefined,
        };
    },
};


export interface RuleInputRequestWithParamsDto {
    id: string;
    dto: RuleInputDto;
}

export interface RuleRpcService<Context extends GrpcContext = GrpcContext> {
    ruleCreateOne(request: RuleMessage, ctx: Context): Promise<RuleMessage>;
    

    ruleCreateMany(
        request: RuleCreateBulkRequestDto,
        ctx: Context
    ): Promise<{ rules: RuleMessage[] }>;
```

from proto file :

```
 rpc RuleCreateMany(com.mevris.server.repository.Rule.RuleCreateBulkRequestDto) returns (com.mevris.server.repository.Rule.ManyRulesDto) {}
```

Comment: if any further detail need i can post here ? thanks in advance .. waiting reply..

Comment: the [object Object] is simply because you are not stringifying your result. result.json() or JSON.stringify(result) should give you a cleaner output

Comment: json() no exist . if do  JSON.stringify(result)  then give '[object Objbect]'

Comment: json() no exist . if do  JSON.stringify(result)  then give '[object Objbect]'

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(x)`
prints only the root properties. Every other complex property will be omitted by declaring the type of it and not the data.

If you want to print out the complete object with all the inner properties you should use JSON.stringify like this:
`console.log(JSON.stringify(x))`

Comment: no bro not this problem . thanks for update